# ActionTypes.Call buttons is missing in Skype Mobile

Tags: button, botframework, chatbot, skype

I made a simple bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and i am using my bot on Skype but theres an error. In emulator i can see the buttons(which type is Call) but in mobile version i cant see the Call buttons. So please help me to see ActionTypes.Call buttons.

Comment: Not all channels support every button type.  It is not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish. Have you tried an OpenUrl button type with 'tell:8888887000' url string?

Comment: Hi @reardeltoit, do you use rich cards? Please share the code you are using to create the buttons. Besides, are the buttons just missing in Skype Mobile? Does it work with Skype for Desktop or web Skype?